# Magento2 MSI Install on 2.3.4

Tags: magento2.3, msi

Trying to install `https://github.com/magento/inventory` on our Magento Enterprise Cloud v2.3.4

however, am getting this error and am not sure if anyone else has experienced this and figured out how to resolve it?

Hoping someone could give me some suggestions.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can get the missing Magento Inventory (a.k.a MSI) packages from: https://github.com/magento/inventory

For Magento 2.3.x you need to get the latest 1.1.x release.

copy all module folders to app/code/Magento and run:

> php bin/magento s:up